# How to reload a page based on a dropdown box

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jsp page that contains a dynamically populated table.  The data that populates the table will be decided by a drop down box. I figure this can be done in javascript, but unfortunately, I am not well versed in JS.  So here is some example code:

```
      <p> Please select a number:
    <select name="selectNumber" id="selectNumber">
      <option value="1" <%if (number.equals("1")) {%>selected<%}%>>1</option>
      <option value="2" <%if (number.equals("2")) {%>selected<%}%>>2</option>
      <option value="3" <%if (number.equals("3")) {%>selected<%}%>>3</option>
      <option value="4" <%if (number.equals("4")) {%>selected<%}%>>4</option>
      <option value="5" <%if (number.equals("5")) {%>selected<%}%>>5</option>
      <option value="6" <%if (number.equals("6")) {%>selected<%}%>>6</option>
    </select>
  </p>
```

So I am using a dropdown like this, and getting the parameter number like this:

```
if (request.getParameter("selectNumber") !=null) {number =    (String)request.getParameter("selectNumber")     ;}
```

So basically I was wondering if there is a script I can do to reload the page once one of the dropdowns is selected, that will allow me to populate my table with the given "number"?  Also, I am not opposed to doing this with AJAX/jQuery, I would just need some tips on that, because I have never used AJAX calls before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you open to using javascript frameworks? Are you looking for just the table to reload or entire page? Basically you will want to bind a handler to the "change" event for the given select box and either hit the page again or use ajax to update the table. If you use a framework like jQuery the ajax call will be much more streamlined than without.

Comment: @scrappedcola See I know less about ajax/jQuery than I do about javascript, but I would not be opposed to that.  The page doesnt have a ton of content, so reloading the entire page vs reloading only the table wouldnt be a huge difference.  And to be honest I am not familiar with javascript frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to change the page location (a JavaScript redirect) using the following code:

```
window.location = 'http://server.com/page.asp';
```

Attach that code to the onchange event for the select box and it will redirect to a page. You'll probably also want to attach an onclick event to each option within the select box as the onchange event only fires once the select box looses focus. You can send data via GET that represents the value of the selected option.

See the example below. Note the onchange (attached to the select) and the onclick (attached to the option).

```
<select name="selectNumber" id="selectNumber" onchange="window.location = 'http://server.com/page.asp?value=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value="1" <%if (number.equals("1")) {% onclick="window.location = 'http://server.com/page.asp?value=' + this.value;">selected<%}%>>1</option>
  ...
</select>
```